# Mysql multi-table / multi-entity related content query

Tags: mysql, related-content

I've got the following tables:

- magazine_tags
- news_tags
- page_tags
- content_tags
- faq_tags

They all have exactly the same structure:

```
uid_local - id of the entity
uid_foreign - id of the tag
```

Each one of them maps to a Model in PHP.

I need to get related content based on multiple tags. Say I'm viewing an "faq" tagged with 1 and 4, I need to get all items tagged with either 1 or 4, but those tagged with both should be at the top.

I also need to be able to distinguish between the different entities, so I can load them up using their corresponding model in PHP after I run the query.

How would I go about building this query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it because I'm mobile but the following should do the trick:

SELECT uid_local, uid_foreign, count(*) as frequency FROM faq_tags WHERE uid_foreign IN (1,4) GROUP BY uid_local ORDER BY frequency DESC

Comment: That actually worked fine, but is there any way to expand it so it runs on multiple tables at once?

Comment: You could try joining them or union select.

PS: [ro] cand mai treci prin Bucuresti sa iesim la o bere :) [/ro]

Comment: I ended up with a combination of union and concat: `CONCAT('Model_Class_', uid_local) as uid_local` and then in PHP I'll strip off the model class when processing the result. Thanks!